# Apache php fpm default config if error in htacess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, config

In Apache server, i've several PHP version installed in FPM mode. All works fine with this conf :

```
    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            SetHandler php7
    </Directory>

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    #PHP 5
        Action php5 /php5
        Alias /php5 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 -socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
    #PHP 7
        Action php7 /php7
        Alias /php7 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7 -socket /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

When i use SetHandler in .htaccess file, it's works too :

```
 SetHandler php5
```

But, if an user make some mistakes in .htaccess , like here :

```
SetHandler php5.6
```

The browser return PHP code (security break)  :

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

How i can manage correctly the apache.conf for security, and
load only a PHP default version if there an user mistake in htaccess file ?

I try this config, but make only PHP7 version by default.
Here, users can't changes anything in .htaccess file :

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
SetHandler php7
</FilesMatch>
```

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 0):

Now i find the solution with `SetEnv` setting in default PHP config.
Need's Apache 2.4 mod : **CGI-proxy** and **Macro**

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi
a2enmod macro
```

Working config for Ubuntu Server 16.04 (ex. *phpfpm.conf* file) :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5

<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>

   ProxyErrorOverride on

   <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">

        <Macro PHPver $ver $cgipath>
                <If "env('PHP_VER') == '$ver'">
                SetHandler '$cgipath'
                </If>
        </Macro>

        #PHP VERSIONS WITH SOCKET OR HOST :
        Use PHPver 7 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        Use PHPver 5 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        Use PHPver 5.4 'proxy:fcgi://localhost:9054'
        Use PHPver 5.5 'proxy:fcgi://localhost:9055'
        Use PHPver 5.6 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        Use PHPver 7.0 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        Use PHPver 7.1 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        Use PHPver 7.2 'proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost'
        #ELSE IF (default version) :
        SetHandler 'proxy:fcgi://localhost:9054'

   </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Now we can correctly call the PHP version in **.htaccess** file, by :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 7.0
```